# How to distribute 4 components in UITableViewCell with autolayout?

Tags: ios, uiview, autolayout, constraints

I have a view with an UITableViewCell. In this custom cell like this:
[image]

I have added the textFields into UIViews, and all uiviews have this constraints with autolayout:

[image]

but then, when is running on device, all views are distributed with bad forms:

[image]

The first uiview is deformed

How could I add the constraints correctly to show this like into sttoryboard (First picture) ?
Thanks!

Comment: what about stack views?

Comment: Available in iOS 9.0 and later and I need iOS 8 @TusharSharma

Answer (score 0):

```
width >= 62
```

means you set the min width for each component. *UILabel* is auto size based on its content, that’s the reason why you got the result. To achieve your goal, set component to equal width to each other

In storyboard, you can do that by pressing *Ctrl* while dragging mouse to other component and select equal width